# Angular custom validation using http service - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error when I run my code: Cannot read property 'getClientEmails' of undefined.
It works if I call 'clientService' from ngOnInit, but not from inside the 'shouldBeUnique' method

```
export class ClientFormComponent {

  emails: any = {};

  form = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('',
      null,
      this.shouldBeUnique),

    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    confirm: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    firstname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    lastname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    address: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    phone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    medical: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  constructor(public clientService: ClientService) { }


  shouldBeUnique(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {

    this.clientService.getClientEmails().subscribe(email => {
      this.emails = email;
      console.log(this.emails);
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if (control.value === '')
        resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
      else
        resolve(null);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of making a service call and returning a promise, since your validator only checks if the control value is empty or not?

Comment: I'll replace the empty string with a real check when I have the service call working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
this.shouldBeUnique
```

by

```
(control: AbstractControl) => this.shouldBeUnique(control)
```